# podman error: ERRO[0013] failed to move the rootless netns slirp4netns process to the systemd user.slice: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited

Tags: podman

After su to a regular user, when I run

```
podman run --network=podman" -it ubi8
```

I get the error

```
ERRO[0013] failed to move the rootless netns slirp4netns process to the systemd user.slice: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
```

And in in the system log, /var/log/messages:

```
Jan 26 12:16:39 ezb5568 dbus-daemon[145488]: Cannot setup inotify for '/root/.local/share/dbus-1/services'; error 'Permission denied'
Jan 26 12:16:39 ezb5568 dbus-daemon[145488]: [session uid=0 pid=145486] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' requested by ':1.0' (uid=0 pid=145470 comm="podman run --network=podman")
Jan 26 12:16:39 ezb5568 dbus-daemon[145488]: [session uid=0 pid=145486] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Run podman as another user interactively

```
$ sudo -i
# machinectl shell username@
Connected to the local host. Press ^] three times within 1s to exit session.
$ podman run --rm -ti docker.io/library/alpine
/ # cat /etc/alpine-release 
3.17.3
/ #
```

A side note: On a Fedora 38 system the command `machinectl` is located in the package
**systemd-container**

```
$ rpm -qf /usr/bin/machinectl
systemd-container-253-1.fc38.aarch64
```

#### Run podman as another user noninteractively

```
# sudo systemd-run \
         --machine=username@ \
         --quiet \
         --user \
         --collect \
         --pipe \
         --wait \
           podman run \
              --rm \
              docker.io/library/alpine \
                  echo hello
hello
```

A sidenote: On a Fedora 38 system the command `systemd-run` is located in the package
**systemd**

```
$ rpm -qf /usr/bin/systemd-run
systemd-253-1.fc38.aarch64
```

#### The reason `su` should be avoided when running podman as another user

As to why not use `su` see the blog post

*Why can't I run rootless Podman containers when I log into a user via sudo or su?* https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/sudo-rootless-podman

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to change to another user with which you'll run podman, you'll need to do a console login as that user or `ssh user@localhost`. Using `su` contaminates the shell environment of the user you switch to with variables set by the originating user(s). This is a known issue with podman. I had been doing `sudo su - user`, but this led to failures when running podman. Using `-` or `--login` is not sufficient, and one needs to use `ssh` or do a console login. There are workarounds, but in my experience they are not reliable.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).